# Sharing field constraint metadata between Java DTO layer and Java Entity layer

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase, bean-validation, liquibase-hibernate

I have a Java Entity class and a Java Data Transfer Object, each of which has it's own layer of validation based on constraints.

I use Liquibase to generate changelogs (db schema) based on the state of the Java Entity classes.
But there is a bug in the `liquibase-hibernate` integration dependency which is not mapping Bean Validation constraints such as `@NotNull` or `@Size` into the corresponding Liquibase changelogs:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/149

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/301

This means the only way I can specify constraints for the database is inside the JPA `@Column` annotation.

I wont be able to group the Bean Validation constraints used at the DTO layer into a composite annotation for use at the Java Entity layer, as it will simply be ignored anyway. Resulting in having to duplicate the constraint info into the `@Column` annotation.

What is the best practice for sharing constraint metadata between the separate DTO and DB layers?

- A composite annotation containing all Bean Validation and JPA constraints? e.g `@Size`, `@NotNull`, `@Column`
- Is there a library that facilitates sharing between the layers?
- Or is it expected that no Bean Validation constraints should be specified inside Java Entity and duplication cannot be avoided?

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class ItemOne {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false, length = 100)
    String text;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

The associated DTO which has the Bean Validation constraints applied to fields:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class ItemOneDTO {


    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    String text;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```